# How to merge two GA4 settings? Is it possible?

Tags: merge, settings, google-analytics-4

My software engineer create a account for a client but he made two settings in GA4. For examples, there are website setting and App setting which is connected with firebase. The problem is my client wants to check the data of website and App traffic in one setting. Is there any chance to merge those two settings in GA4? If you know how to do it please let me know. Much thanks in advance.

I tried to find the solution in website like stack overflow and others but there are no information about merge those two settings. I want to merger or add one to another. If I set the new setting for website data and App in GA4 , then there is going to be a problem because programmer must code a new source from GA4 and need to distribute in app store again. We need to pay the bill for it again and my client doesn't want it. That's the problem.